# Understanding the PyTorch implementation of Conv2DTranspose

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to understand an example snippet that makes use of the PyTorch transposed convolution function, with documentation [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html), where in the docs the author writes:

> "The padding argument effectively adds dilation * (kernel_size - 1) -
> padding amount of zero padding to both sizes of the input."

Consider the snippet below where a sample image of shape `[1, 1, 4, 4]` containing all ones is input to a `ConvTranspose2D` operation with arguments `stride=2` and `padding=1` with a weight matrix of shape `(1, 1, 4, 4)` that has entries from a range between `1` and `16` (in this case `dilation=1` and `added_padding = 1*(4-1)-1 = 2`)

```
sample_im = torch.ones(1, 1, 4, 4).cuda()
sample_deconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(1, 1, 4, 2, 1, bias=False).cuda()
sample_deconv.weight = torch.nn.Parameter(
    torch.tensor([[[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.], 
                    [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.], 
                    [ 9., 10., 11., 12.], 
                    [13., 14., 15., 16.]]]]).cuda())
```

Which yields:

```
>>> sample_deconv(sample_im)
tensor([[[[ 6., 12., 14., 12., 14., 12., 14.,  7.],
          [12., 24., 28., 24., 28., 24., 28., 14.],
          [20., 40., 44., 40., 44., 40., 44., 22.],
          [12., 24., 28., 24., 28., 24., 28., 14.],
          [20., 40., 44., 40., 44., 40., 44., 22.],
          [12., 24., 28., 24., 28., 24., 28., 14.],
          [20., 40., 44., 40., 44., 40., 44., 22.],
          [10., 20., 22., 20., 22., 20., 22., 11.]]]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<CudnnConvolutionTransposeBackward>)
```

Now I have seen simple examples of transposed convolution without stride and padding. For instance, if the input is a `2x2` image  `[[2, 4], [0, 1]]`, and the convolutional filter with one output channel is `[[3, 1], [1, 5]]`, then the resulting tensor of shape `(1, 1, 3, 3)` can be seen as the sum of the four colored matrices in the image below:

[image]

The problem is I can't seem to find examples that use strides and/or padding in the same visualization. As per my snippet, I am having a very difficult time understanding how the padding is applied to the sample image, or how the stride works to get this output. Any insights appreciated, even just understanding how the `6` in the `(0,0)` entry or the `12` in the `(0,1)` entry of the resulting matrix are computed would be very helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The output spatial dimensions of [`nn.ConvTranspose2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html) are given by:

```
out = (x - 1)s - 2p + d(k - 1) + op + 1
```

where `x` is the *input* spatial dimension and `out` the corresponding *output* size, `s` is the stride, `d` the dilation, `p` the padding, `k` the kernel size, and `op` the output padding.

---

If we keep the following operands:

[image]

For each value of the input, we compute a buffer (of the corresponding color) by calculating the product with each element of the kernel.

Here are the visualizations for `s=1, p=0`, `s=1, p=1`, `s=2, p=0`, and `s=2, p=1`:

- `s=1, p=0`: output is `3x3`

[image]

For the **blue buffer**, we have (1) `2*k_top-left = 2*3 = 6`; (2) `2*k_top-right = 2*1 = 2`; (3) `2*k_bottom-left = 2*1 = 2`; (4) `2*k_bottom-right = 2*5 = 10`.

- `s=1, p=1`: output is `1x1`

[image]

- `s=2, p=0`: output is `4x4`

[image]

- `s=2, p=2`: output is `2x2`

[image]

Comment: Ok! I think the crux of my confusion is the what the $p$ argument does, If I understand correctly, its as if when p=1, you are removing one column and one row from each side of the four matrices that are being added?  Almost like a kind of "anti" - padding Thanks a lot for the great answer, I hope this will be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Should it be `s=2, p=1` in the last example?

Answer (score 6):

I believe what makes things confusing is that they are not very careful about what they meant by "input" or "output" in the doc, and the overloading of the terms "stride" and "padding".

I found it easier to understand transposed convolution in PyTorch by asking myself: What arguments would I give to a normal, forward convolution layer such that it would give the tensor at hand, that I'm feeding into a transposed conv layer?

For instance, "stride" should be understood as the "stride" in a **forward** conv, i.e. the moving step of the sliding kernel.

In a transposed conv, "stride" actually means something different: `stride-1` is the number of the interleaving empty slots in between the input units into the **transposed** conv layer. That's because it is the greater-than-1 "strides" in a **forward** conv that create such holes. See image below for an illustration:

[image]

The illustration also shows that **the kernel moving step in a transposed conv layer is always 1, regardless of the value of "stride"**. I found it very important to keep this in mind.

Similar for the `padding` argument. It should be understood as the 0-padding applied to the **forward** conv. Because of this padding, we get some extra units in the output from the **forward** conv. So, if we then feed this output into a transposed conv, in order to get back to the original, non-padded length, those extra things should be removed, thus the `-2p` term in the equation.

See image below for an illustration.

In summary, these are designed as such that normal conv and transposed conv are "inverse" operations to each other, in the sense of tensor shape transformations. (But I do believe that the doc should be improved.)

With this principle in mind, one can also work out the `dilation` and `output_padding` arguments relatively easily. I've written a [blog](https://numbersmithy.com/understanding-transposed-convolutions-in-pytorch)  on this, in case anyone is interested.

[image]