# What happens in a convolution when the stride is larger than the kernel?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I recently was experiment with convolutions and transposed convolutions in Pytorch. I noticed with the `nn.ConvTranspose2d` API (I haven't tried with the normal convolution API yet), you can specify a stride that is larger than the kernel size and the convolution will still work.

What is happening in this case? I'm confused because if the stride is larger than the kernel, that means some pixels in the input image will not be convolved. So what happens to them?

I have the following snippet where I manually set the weights for a `nn.ConvTranspose2d` layer:

```py
IN = 1
OUT = 1
KERNEL_SIZE = 2
proof_conv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(IN, OUT, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, stride=4)
assert proof_conv.weight.shape == (IN, OUT, KERNEL_SIZE, KERNEL_SIZE)

FILTER = [
    [1., 2.],
    [0., 1.]
]
weights = [
    [FILTER]
]

weights_as_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(weights)).float()
assert weights_as_tensor.shape == proof_conv.weight.shape
proof_conv.weight = nn.Parameter(weights_as_tensor)

img = [[
  [1., 2.],
  [3., 4.]
]]
img_as_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.asarray(img)).float()
out_img = proof_conv(img_as_tensor)
assert out_img.shape == (OUT, 6, 6)
```

The stride is larger than the `KERNEL_SIZE` of 2. Yet, the transposed convolution still occurs and we get an output of 6x6. What is happening underneath the hood?

This post: [Understanding the PyTorch implementation of Conv2DTranspose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69782823/understanding-the-pytorch-implementation-of-conv2dtranspose) is helpful but does not answer the edge-case of when the stride is greater than the kernel.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this thread: [***Understanding PyTorch implementation of `nn.ConvTranspose2d`***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69782823/understanding-the-pytorch-implementation-of-conv2dtranspose). If you require additional information, let me know.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks! That was a pretty great explanation. I can see from the explanation that the `padding` parameter actually shrinks the size of the output. However, I still don't understand how the algorithm functions when the stride is greater than the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already guessed - when the stride is larger than the kernel size, there are input pixels that do not participate in the convolution operation.
It's up to you - the designer of the architecture to decide whether this property is a bug or a feature. In some cases, I took advantage of this property to ignore portions of the inputs.

**Update:**
I think you are being confused by the bias term in `proof_conv`. Try to eliminate it:

```py
proof_conv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(IN, OUT, kernel_size=KERNEL_SIZE, stride=4, bias=False)
```

Now you'll get `out_img` to be:

```py
[[[[1., 2., 0., 0., 2., 4.],
          [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 2.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
          [3., 6., 0., 0., 4., 8.],
          [0., 3., 0., 0., 0., 4.]]]]
```

Which represent 4 copies of the kernel, weighted by the input image, spaced 4 pixels apart according to `stride=4`.
The rest of the output image is filled with zeros - representing pixels that do not contribute to the transposed convolution.

[`ConvTranspose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html#torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d) follows the same "logic" as the regular `conv`, only in a "transposed" fashion. If you look at the formula for computing output shape you'll see that the behavior you get is consistent.

Comment: I thought pixels would not participate in the convolution, but this seems false because if I set the stride to `12`, the output matrix will have dimensions of 12 by something (even if the input matrix is only 2x2)

Comment: You can also look at my code example, which shows that setting stride=4 results in a 6x6 output even though the input is 2x2.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `ConvTranspose2D` will *always* use all of the pixels in the input image, regardless of the `stride` and `kernel_size`. This is different than for `Conv2D`. As you can see by looking at the actual values in `out_img` (as seen in @Shai's answer), each value is used to generate the four  sets of 2x2 values at the corners of the image. `stride` in `ConvTranspose2D` instead affects the output image size and spacing. You can see that because `stride=4` in this case, the 4 2x2 results of the 2x2 inputs and 2x2 kernel are spaced 4 units apart. The intervening spaces are filled with zeros, as some of the *output* pixels will have no input if `stride` > `kernel_size`.

This is essentially the corollary of some *input* cells not being used in `Conv2D` if `stride` > `kernel_size`. I think maybe this is what you were trying to get at with your question.